# EF stored procedure with dynamic number of columns in result set

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

At first I should note that I'm new in ASP.NET (however, I have some experience with C#) and Entity Framework. I work on a school project and there is quite complicated database containing energy consumption data. Those I need (`I` import, `E` export, reactive power `C` and `L`) are stored in one column as binary compressed so to get them out I have to use a stored procedure which calls some methods in custom assembly to decompress the column and restore the data.

The stored procedure has 4 arguments:

```
@identify int,
@startTime datetime,
@endTime datetime,
@args nvarchar(60) -- "Selector"
```

The `selector` is rather special, it's an argument where you specify what you want in the result set, e.g. `'i'` for Import column only, `'i,e'` for Import and Export. They designed it like this because it's faster if you need just one column rather then all columns (because of the way the compressed data are stored).

So, I've created an ADO.NET Entity Model called `EnergyConsumptionDBModel`, imported the stored procedure and created complex type `EnergyConsumptionResult` for the stored procedure return type as follows:

```
public partial class EnergyConsumptionResult
{
    public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double I { get; set; }
    public double E { get; set; }
    public double L { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
}
```

The column `Time` is always present in the result set, but the rest depends on the `@args` argument of the stored procedure. For example if I pick `'i,e,c,l'` as an argument, it will return columns `Time, I, E, C, L` and everything is just fine but if I pick for example `'i'` it returns `Time, I` which gives me an exception:

> *The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EnergyConsumptionDBModel.EnergyConsumptionResult'.*
>   *A member of the type, 'E', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.*

So the question is, is there some simple way to solve this? Some kind of dynamic result mapping on complex type or is it much more simple to tell my colleague who designed the stored procedure to make it return all columns whatever is in `@args` but leave the un-used columns empty which is a solution my project leader may not like. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have to use entity framework? You could use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to capture the result in a dynamic type.

Comment: @GertArnold Entity Framework is not a requirement. Although I've already solved my problem by using wrapper procedure (I don't really like it, but it works), I will definitely look at this.

Comment: @RiZe Did you come up with a solution for this that you can share? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: @PostureOfLearning Actually yes, kind of. I have created a wrapping stored procedure in which a table with all columns present was created and then the original stored procedure was executed for each variable (I, E, L, C) if present in `@args`. Then the table was returned with NULL values in columns which were not required. Unfortunatelly I will probably not be able to find that piece of code as the original stored procedure was abandoned during development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to automatically map resultsets with variable number of columns in EF. You specify the mapping at design time and EF relies on that. What you could do would be returning all columns but set the columns for which you don't return data to null. You may try using executing the stored procedure directly and use Translate method on ObjectContext (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx) for materialization but I think this method will also expect columns in your reader that correspond to property names.

Comment: Looks like I will have to create a wrapping procedure around that stored procedure. My project leader doesn't like the idea of modifying the stored procedure itself this way.